# How can I request focus to specfic text field in webview?

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I want to open keyboard immediately after opening my app. For example If I load google.com in webview then search field should be tapped automatically and keyboard should be shown.

My code:

```
   webView.loadUrl("http://google.com");
```

When user opens the activity, directly field of search should be selected and keyboard should be visible instead of him tapping manually on that. Is there a way?

Comment: try :`Webview.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN|View.FOCUS_UP);`

Comment: Not working. Please tell me how can I use it with https://instantdomainsearch.com/widget/liquid/

Answer (score 2):

Try add this:

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByName('q')[0].focus();");
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }
});

InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT, 0);
```

Comment: You are GOD! Please tell me how can I use it with this? https://instantdomainsearch.com/widget/liquid/

Comment: Use this `view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByClassName('searchInput')[0].focus();");`

Comment: keyboard is visible for less than a second. but it becomes invisible again.